# How to debug "Load report failed" when opening Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RppkH.png)[image: Image 1]

Error:

```
Crystal Reports
Load report failed
```

Note  : when i  delete special  code report OK

Code:

```
if {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0258" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0259" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0260" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0261" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0262" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0263" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0264" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0265" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0266" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0267" or {@ITEMNO}= "1201.0268" then "\\192.168.1.250\Sage 300 ERP\PIC\TotalTools\"+ "1201.0257" +".jpg"
```

Comment: this code in report and path

Comment: any some one help

Comment: Can you explain more please. I cant completely understand u

Comment: Dear when i tray open report from system " sage erp 300"  show this message " load report failed " but when tray open from  server direct by crystal report its ok  so i cant open by the system  please sir i need help i take more time but no result and please see im new in crystal report

Comment: this report continue more picture by link as formula up

Comment: @ITEMNO is a text? if not try using `totext()` function

Comment: Are the rest of your data displayed OK when you run the statement from your system? What kind of RDBMS do you use?